# android listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a list view in my app and which grows dynamically. Initially list contains same contents for entire list row. Each row in list view displays different contents as app progress. I used same list view foe displaying two type of contents. But the problem is when this happens the scrolling of list view become less smooth. please tell me why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you just provide me that link...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is hard to tell what the problem is without looking at the code anyways are you using remote images in that listview? or custom listview you have created using base or arrayadapter? if yes then you will have definately perfomance related issue.

Comment: if custom adapter then avoid creating views every time. using a small if else check with tags you see in examples

Comment: yes i'm using custom adapter. In this i have listener for each row contents, which updates the that list view row.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause I've seen for this so far, is re-creating your View every time it's requested. You should rather see if the current View on your Handler is not created already. If it's created just update it, don't re-create it. If it's not then bring it from the scratch with new and all that stuff.

Basic Android List tutorials have some lines like (I can't remember exactly):

```
if(v == null){
    v = new MyView(...);
}else{
    ((MyView)v).updateData();
}
return v;
```

Pay close attention to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you just provide me that link...?

Comment: This is an example: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327 check for the `public View getView` method